# Nested transactions in kotlin exposed

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I am looking for a way to rollback parent transaction if child transaction was rollbacked.
I am using kotlin and exposed framework.
This is the example code:

```
transaction{

transaction {} 
transaction {rollback()}

}
```

In above example I used rollback in child transaction.
I would like to achieve automatic rollback for first children and parent transactions.
Is there any way to achieve that?